# Неверный результат при умножении двух матриц

Tags: c#

***C#:***

```
using System;

public class MatrixMult {
 public static void Main() {
  MultiplyMatrix();
 }
 public static void MultiplyMatrix() {
  var a = new [, ] {
   {5,10,13,-4,10}, 
   {20,2,9,9,-1}, 
   {5,10,4,8,14}, 
   {6,1,2,6,10}, 
   {95,5,10,10,2}};
  var b = new [, ] {
   {5,10,8,-4,62}, 
   {20,2,9,9,-1}, 
   {5,10,1,8,1}, 
   {6,1,2,6,-5}, 
   {95,5,1,3,2}};
  var c = new [, ] {
   {0,0,0,0,0}, 
   {0,0,0,0,0}, 
   {0,0,0,0,0}, 
   {0,0,0,0,0}, 
   {0,0,0,0,0}};

  for (int i = 0; i < c.GetLength(0); i++) {
   for (int k = 0; k < c.GetLength(1); k++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < a.GetLength(1); j++) {
     c[i, k] += a[j, k] * b[i, j];
    }
    Console.Write("{0} ", c[i, k]);
   }
   Console.WriteLine();
  }
  Console.ReadKey();
 }
}
```

Результат по выполнении:

```
6131 456 799 730 236
144 298 322 54 412
373 93 185 136 136
-379 63 57 -13 137
788 983 1310 -289 993
```

Нужно такой результат:

```
25 100 104 16 620
400 4 81 81 1
25 100 4 64 14
36 1 4 36 -50
9025 25 10 30 4
```

Comment: Вы в этом уверены "c[i, k] += a[j, k] * b[i, j]" ? И еще умножение матриц возможно, если число строк в первом сомножителе равно числу столбцов во втором.

Comment: Выровняйте код нормально, все-таки не первый раз задаете вопрос. Напишите также что именно неверно, что должно было получиться и почему.

Comment: @defaultlocale, зачем на вопрос минус ставить?

Comment: За что минус я написал в предыдущем комментарии. После правок минус убрал и голос за закрытие отозвал.

Comment: c[i, k] += a[i, j] * b[j,k];

Comment: Я бы попробовал бы для начала умножить матрицы 2 на 2. Тогда можно будет пройтись по шагам и быстро найти косяк.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Что-то не так с результатом**

В `c[0][0]` после перемножения должно получиться скалярное произведение первой строки a и первого столбца b.

Расчет (псевдокод):

```
c[0][0] 
    = a[0]*b[0]
    = {5,10,13,-4,10} * {5,20,5,6,95}
    = 5*5 + 10*20 + 13*5 + (-4)*6 + 10*95 
    = 1216
```

Т.е. должно быть 1216, а не 25. Если матрицы должны быть каким-либо образом преобразованы, уточните это в вопросе и напишите как должен быть выполнен расчет.

**Что-то не так с кодом**

В строке:

```
 c[i, k] += a[j, k] * b[i, j];
```

у Вас перемножаются столбец `a` со строкой `b`, чтобы было наоборот замените строку на следующую:

```
 c[i, k] += a[i, j] * b[j, k];
```

Чтобы легче было представить можно выписать индексы и выделить их в матрицах. Либо адаптировать формулу из статьи «[Умножение матриц](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86)» в Википедии:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как уже написал @iluxa1810 в комментариях, код проще отлаживать на минимальных примерах (сначала добиться работы для матриц 2X2, 3X3; проверить матрицы с неравным числом строк и столбцов: 2X3, 2X4; затем переходить к контрольным примерам).

Comment: Спасибо, но странно этот результат не принимают

Comment: @KillNoise Пожалуйста! С тем что не принимают я ничего поделать не могу.

Comment: в задаче 3-ей матрицы `c` не было, прийшлось дописать так как по другому не знал как результат выводить

Comment: @KillNoise тут важно понять каким образом был получен эталонный результат. Как выводить это уже детали.

Comment: Лучше 2*3, чем 2*2 и 3*3 - помогает от проблем с перепутанными размерностями.

Comment: @Qwertiy и вправду! внес в ответ, спасибо! с наступающим!